# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when converting inputted time | SQL, SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a problem with this query. I'm receiving the following error below.

**What I'm trying to do is to convert the 10:00 PM to 22:00, basically from 12 hour format to 24 hour format.**

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The value of the schedulename column is

*10:00 PM - 06:00 AM*

*10:00 PM - 06:00 AM*

and one row called *REST*

I set it to `LEFT(schedulename,8)` so that I can get the schedule on the left, and then `RIGHT(schedulename,8)` so that I can get the schedule on the right.

I'm using SQLSRV, SQLSERVER 2012, and XAMPP.

```
SELECT 
Format(cast(LEFT(schedulename,8) as datetime),'HH:mm:ss') AS login,
Format(cast(RIGHT(schedulename,8) as datetime),'HH:mm:ss') AS logout 
FROM
employeesschedulelist 
WHERE 
employeeidno='D0150000005'
```

I also tried this, but no luck.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEFT(schedulename,8), 108) as login,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, RIGHT(schedulename,8), 108) as logout 
from employeesschedulelist 
where employeeidno='D0150000005'
```

Is there another solution to this without changing my column?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/53812 - perhaps the value in the column isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Qirel, I don't understand, why does it work perfectly in sqlfiddle? could it be that I'm using SQL SERVER 2012?

Comment: I would take a wild guess that your column isn't exactly `10:00 PM - 06:00 AM`, perhaps there's some whitespace or other characters in it.

Comment: are you sure len(schedulename) = 19 ? (I suppose like @Qirel there should be some more whitespaces, perhaps leading, trailing or in the middle of the string)

Comment: @Qirel I edited my post, I double checked my column, there's a row value inside it called *REST*, is there a way for us to somehow bypass this and continue converting?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I edited my post. Please check, Is there a way for it to somewhat ignore the query when it runs on the *REST* value?

Comment: Use `try_cast`. This function returns `null` for invalid cast and it's available in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CAST()` instead of `CAST()`. If the conversion fails, it will return `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(TRY_CAST(LEFT(schedulename ,8) AS DATETIME),'HH:mm:ss') AS login,
       FORMAT(TRY_CAST(RIGHT(schedulename, 8) AS DATETIME),'HH:mm:ss') AS logout 
FROM employeesschedulelist 
WHERE employeeidno = 'D0150000005'
```

- [`TRY_CAST()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Live SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5dc011d9387c6e7b904cd807a49e0d24)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(TIME,(LEFT(schedulename,8))) AS login,
CONVERT(TIME,(RIGHT(schedulename,8))) AS logout 
FROM employeesschedulelist 
WHERE employeeidno='D0150000005'
```

Comment: I saw what was causing the problem, the value in the column called *REST*, is there a way for us to bypass that somehow and continue with the query?